# Virtual Sdcard, wont be created, android

Tags: android-emulator

Ok basically im in the process of creating an app that loads gestures I build from the guester builder program inside the emulator.  But everytime I run the app on my phone It says that It cant find the sd card or none of the gestures I built are there.

I read online that I need to create and SDcard inside the emulator and read that I need to open up mySDcard inside android-sdk-tools  but when I open mySdCard.exe it just brings up the command view for a split second and closes.  So my questions is How do i go about creating an sdcard for the emulator.

Now I already built one when, building the meulator in the popup screen that says SDCARD size(input size here).  But when i go to where my emulator is located I do not see an sdcard file.  Is it hidden? is it not inside the .android file? or am I just completely stupid and missing it?  If i need to manually create one how would I do that?

Thank you (if you need to see code just let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating SDCard on your Emulator you should also select `SD Card support` from `Hardware` options which you are creating your Emulator. Make sure that you have given the SD Card support to the Emulator that you are creating also don't forget to give the SD Card size.

Then you can just goto `DDMS->File Explorer` and check that your SDCard is creating by pushing a file onto the SDCard.

Comment: Let me try that and see how it works, Also i just looking in the DDMS as you posted this and saw my gestures file in the sdcard how would I go about moving that to the Raw file?

Comment: If you want to move your file in your raw folder you have to manually push it from the device and put it in the raw folder.

Comment: Ok, i actually pulled it from the emulator into the location where my raw file was on my project I am testing it now but thank you so much for the help I think I got it from here.  Thank you